# How can I have the user choose between Nested Lists in my program?

Tags: python, input, replace, nested-lists

I was trying to create a game where the user could first choose between 3 different maps to go through, then input words like "left" and "grab" to move through the chosen map (like a text based game). Most of the program uses list methods and if statements. The part I got stuck on was the map choosing, which uses nested lists.

This is what I tried:

```
choose = input("What floor plan would you like?: 1, 2, or 3?: ")
if choose == 2:
    2 == plan2
    plan = plan.replace(plan, plan2)
elif choose == 3:
    plan = plan.replace(plan,plan3)
```

And this is an example of a nested list I had:

```
plan = [
    ['nothing', 'a wooden stake', 'a wooden stake','a vampire','stairs leading up'],
    ['stairs leading down', 'a vampire','a wooden stake', 'a vampire','stairs leading up'],
    ['stairs leading down', 'a silver sword','chocolate','a werewolf','The Wand']
    ]
```

I've tried a variation of things but nothing seems to work. Is how "plan" is used further down stopping it from working properly? I've used it as "plan[floor][room]", which keeps track of where the player is.
I'd rather not try to use anything too complicated as I'm still learning, but let me know if the replace() list method is not something that can work here. Please let me know if this question is too vague or needs to be reworded or deleted. Thank you!

Comment: If `plan` is a list of lists, what are you expecting `plan = plan.replace(plan, plan2)` to do?  A list has no `replace()` method, so this isn't going to work.  It would make more sense if `plan` were a string, but then you're looking inside that string for that string.  That makes no sense.

Comment: For one thing, `input()` returns a string.  So `choose` is a string, and `if choose == 2` can never be true, because `2` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create three *separate* variables

Each one will contain one of the floor plans. Select the one you want.

Don't try to do any `replace`ing. That will create a mess for you.

```
plan1 = [
    ['nothing', 'a wooden stake', 'a wooden stake','a vampire','stairs leading up'],
    ['stairs leading down', 'a vampire','a wooden stake', 'a vampire','stairs leading up'],
    ['stairs leading down', 'a silver sword','chocolate','a werewolf','The Wand']
    ]

plan2 = [
    [..., ..., ...],
    [..., ..., ...],
    [..., ..., ...],
    ]

plan3 = [
    [..., ..., ...],
    [..., ..., ...],
    [..., ..., ...],
    ]


choose = input("What floor plan would you like?: 1, 2, or 3?: ")

if choose == 1:
    plan = plan1
elif choose == 2:
    plan = plan2
elif choose == 3:
    plan = plan3
```